# openpyxl blocking excel file after first read

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to overwrite a value in a given cell using openpyxl. I have two sheets. One is called Raw, it is populated by API calls. Second is Data that is fed off of Raw sheet. Two sheets have exactly identical shape (cols/rows). I am doing a comparison of the two to see if there is a bay assignment in Raw. If there is - grab it to Data sheet. If both Raw and Data have the value in that column missing - then run a complex Algo (irrelevant for this question) to assign bay number based on logic.
I am having problems with rewriting Excel using openpyxl.

Here's example of my code.

```
data_df = pd.read_excel('Algo Build v23test.xlsx', sheet_name='MondayData') 
raw_df = pd.read_excel('Algo Build v23test.xlsx', sheet_name='MondayRaw')
no_bay_res = data_df[data_df['Bay assignment'].isnull()].reset_index() #grab rows where there is no bay assignment in a specific column

book = load_workbook("Algo Build v23test.xlsx")
    sheet = book["MondayData"]
    for index, reservation in no_bay_res.iterrows():
        idx = int(reservation['index'])
        if pd.isna(raw_df.iloc[idx, 13]):
            continue
        else:
            value = raw_df.iat[idx,13]
            data_df.iloc[idx, 13] = value
            sheet.cell(idx+2, 14).value = int(value)
        
    book.save("Algo Build v23test.xlsx")
    book.close()
print(value) #302
```

Now the problem is that it seems that book.close() is not working. Book is still callable in python. Now, it overwrites Excel totally fine. However, if I try to run these two lines again

```
data_df = pd.read_excel('Algo Build v23test.xlsx', sheet_name='MondayData') 
raw_df = pd.read_excel('Algo Build v23test.xlsx', sheet_name='MondayRaw')
```

I am getting datasets full of NULL values, except for the value that was replaced. (attached the image).
[image]
However, if I open that Excel file manually from the folder and save it (CTRL+S) and try running the code again - it works properly. Weirdest problem.
I need to loop the code above for Monday-Sunday, so I need it to be able to read the data again without manually resaving the file.

Answer (score 0):

Due to some reason, pandas will read all the formulas as NaN after the file been used in the script by openpyxl until the file has been opened, saved and closed. Here's the code that helps do that within the script. However, it is rather slow.

```
import xlwings as xl

def df_from_excel(path, sheet_name):
    app = xl.App(visible=False)
    book = app.books.open(path)
    book.save()
    app.kill()
    return pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, the only workaround I found is to terminate the excel.exe manually from taskmanager. After that everything went fine.